# Increase Radar Detection range using Modulation

Tags: radar, frequency-modulation, pulse

I have been reading about pulse compression which helps with the range resolution.

In my application I do not need to measure the range of the object however I am more interested in boosting the SNR so that I can detect the object further. Could pulse compression help with this ?

I am using a low cost radar with FM modulation capability.

Comment: Yes. There are many derivations of the SNR gain from pulse compression available from a internet search.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Pulse compression is really just running the returned signal through a pulse matched filter, which is equivalent to cross correlation.  If you view it as a pulse matched filter, matched filters are optimal for detection of a signal in AWGN.  If you view it as a cross correlation, the output of the correlation will peak when the signal best matches with the filter.